# Sort combobox contents accortding to numbers

Tags: c#

i have a combo box and i populate it with numbers from 1 to 40 but it shows them as 1 than 10-19 than 2 than 20-29 and so on even i tried to insert data trough code

```
for(int i=0;i<41;i++)
Combobox.Items.Inert(i,(i+1).ToString())
```

Also tried above code without conversion to string
but Again it shows same result i think it brings them in ascending order but this is not what i want Kindly Tell me how to do it so that it displays numbers in order from 1-40
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting of a ComboBox is always done [Alphabetically and Ascending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx).

If you don't want this behavior, then you can simply turn it off by setting the `Sorted` property to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this question is what you are looking for](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/cefb6bb1-0fb5-44e7-b9d6-2add9beac11d). You are going to have to do your own sorting and turn off the custom it seems.

From the article, here is the reflector code of the combobox sort (that is private):

```
public int Compare(object item1, object item2)  
{  
    if (item1 == null)  
    {  
        if (item2 == null)  
        {  
            return 0;  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  
    if (item2 == null)  
    {  
        return 1;  
    }  
    string itemText = this.comboBox.GetItemText(item1);  
    string str2 = this.comboBox.GetItemText(item2);  
    return Application.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(itemText, str2, CompareOptions.StringSort);  
}
```

So, it converts everything to string, thus why turning off sort is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox` always adds and sorts objects you add by their "`.ToString()`" function.

What you could always do is add an empty string prior to the numbers:

```
if(i < 10){ (Combo.Items.Add(i.ToString(StringFormat(" i",i)))); }
else { Combo.Items.Add(i); }
```

Then when you retrieve it, parse it as an `int`. (Not as stable as it should be, but a good start).

Answer (score 0):

You could always encapsulate it.

```
public class Item : IComparer
{
public Item(int value) { this.Value = value; }

   public int Value { get; set; }

       public int CompareTo(Item item)
  {
                 int ret = -1;
        if (Value < item.Value)
            ret = -1;
        else if (Value > item.Value)
            ret = 1;
        else if (Value == item.Value)
            ret = 0;
        return ret;
      }

}
```

Then simply...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
  comboBox.Items.Add(new Item(i));
```

Answer (score -1):

try:-

```
for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
combobox.Items.Add((i+1).ToString("D2"));
```

Comment: How is that really any different? The compare logic would still pull it out as a string and run an alpha comparison. You cannot rewrite internal logic

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
for(int i=0;i<41;i++)
Combobox.Items.Add(i);
```